# event.returnValue = false to replace preventdefault not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11

The following works fine everywhere except in IE 11:

```
if( event.keyCode == 18 )
{
    event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false 
    altcurrentstate = "keyisdown";
    Xmouse = x; 
    Ymouse= y;
    return false;   
}
```

I also tried the others ways offered in this site but nope, can't seems to `preventDefault` in IE 11 no matter what, for the alt and arrow keys. The `event.returnValue = false;` trick is not working either. Not working with return false either...

Comment: Can you show more of your code? my guess is you didn't actually define `event` and are instead using the global window.event (which isn't supported in all browsers)

Comment: Like @KevinB said, something else should be wrong. `preventDefault` has been [supported since IE9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975460(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;   this line fixed my problem (y)

Comment: actually your code worked for me with ie11

Comment: Are you using some species of JQuery?

Answer (score 2):

Try actually `return false` in your callback function.

Comment: Where do I put the return false ? Anywhere in the function ? at the end ? my function is'nt supposed to return anything

Comment: huh? what do you mean?

Comment: I mean, in ie11, pressing alt show/hide the menu bar, and it prevent my binding of any function to the alt key. And I tried to return false: in the function and it's still not preventing the default action of alt in ie. preventDefault() works fine in all others browsers I tried....

Comment: try a different key combo - ie might just sandbox that away from you.

Comment: Yes I could, is it possible top make preventDfault works in ie11 ?

Comment: Adding `return false` does not cancel the event in IE11. Why is IE so terrible at everything...

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you need to make your event cancelable using the [initEvent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975960) method.

According to the remarks at the bottom of [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975960):

```
If you cannot cancel the event, calling IDOMEvent::preventDefault has no effect.
When you create a custom event by using the IDocumentEvent::createEvent method, you can set the IDOMEvent::cancelable property by using the IDOMEvent::initEvent method.
```

Comment: And how would I do that, let's say, for the at key ? Because what you says seems to make sense to me, but I don't seem to grasp how to use the initEvent method to set the IDOMEvent to cancelable...or it's a propertie of my eventlistener ? man this looks  like high stuff, teach me please!